# Spelling of R2-D2 (Artoo-Deetoo) and C-3P0 (See-Threepio)

Tags: discussion, spelling

There was some good natured fun in the comments of the question, **[Why Can't Artoo Talk?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8220/why-cant-artoo-talk)** about the spelling of R2-D2. However, it occurred to me that the current spelling (Artoo) makes it harder for people to find the question.

Should we agree on one way to spell these droids? For example:

- **R2-D2** (not Artoo-Deetoo or even R2D2)
- **C-3P0** (not See-Threepio or even C3P0)

This will also mean changing the existing [r2d2 tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2d2).

Comment: I actually edited my [star-wars] question to have these spellings lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't hope everyone to follow an editorial policy in a site that is made of community-generated content. But we can strive to make questions searchable. What I try to do in these situations is include all variant spellings or wordings so that the post will be found whatever variant someone searches for. This can often be done organically, for example using a shorter variant in the question title and a longer variant in the question body.

Comment: This is a good point and may be a good item to include the the FAQ or elsewhere -- a reminder that some terms have multiple spellings and posts are easier to search if all the spellings are referenced in the post.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue I see with this is that if such a guideline is established, only a limited number of people will know about it, so it'll be the responsibility of the moderators to go through and edit all posts with the names spelled out.

But, as for searching abilities, I think as long as R2 is used once in the question or answer, that would make it findable.  Personally, I use Artoo instead of R2 or especially R2D2 because I think it's a pain in the rear to have to use the shift key multiple times or use hit the caps lock key at the start and end of a post (and I think r2d2 is just sloppy).

Comment: Not the responsibility of moderators, everyone can edit posts.

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, but still, it's going to be a few people doing all the editing, since most members won't remember rules like this.

Comment: You have to use the shift key just as much between R2 and Artoo or R2-D2 and Artoo-Deetoo...

Comment: Yes, for R2 and Artoo, it's the same, but I've been typing for something like 35 years and it's easier to use the shift key at the start of a word, as is traditional.  And I've never used the full Artoo-Detoo.