# Change r2d2 tag to r2-d2

Tags: discussion, tags

I've raised the [spelling of R2-D2](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/spelling-of-r2-d2-artoo-deetoo-and-c-3p0-see-threepio). I suggest we change the tag [r2d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2d2) to [r2-d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2-d2). This will be consistent with the "official" spelling and match the [c-3po](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c-3po) tag.

I could retag the questions myself but I think there might be some linking (from r2d2->r2-d2) that requires a moderator's touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few months back, we had a [discussion on tags for *Star Wars* characters](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/843/star-wars-character-tags). The consensus then was that these tags were not necessary. Has something changed? Otherwise we should just remove [r2-d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2-d2), [c-3po](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c-3po) and whatever other ultraspecific tag has crept in. (There's no moderator tool for this, the tag has to be edited out manually.)

In any case, I have created [r2-d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2-d2) and merged [r2d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2d2) into it through the moderator tools.

Comment: Nothing changed: not necessary, but permitted. Unless we decide to remove those Tag from questions, they will still be used.

Comment: Thanks for the retag. I missed that earlier conversation. If the consensus is to remove them, no problem for me.

Comment: I dont absolutely want to keep them, but I just think its a way must user think they should tag their question. It's not a behavior unique to star-wars, the must used character tag is the "voldemor" tag. I think it's related to the use [tag as metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_%28metadata%29) outside this site.

Answer (score 2):

For that purpose, there is something called [Tag synonyms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), you have enough reputation to suggests one.

**DO NOT SUGGEST THE SYNONYM ON THE [r2d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2d2) TAG!** (It will do the opposite of what we want here.)

You should create the [r2-d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2-d2) Tag and retag the questions. You will then have to wait for some script to execute before the rep needed to suggest the synonyms is transfered to the new tag.

Comment: So, on the new r2-d2 tag, add a synonym to r2d2?

Comment: @Wikis exactly.

Comment: I get: *"You are attempting to create the tag r2-d2 ; however the tag r2d2 already exists!"* Help!

Comment: @Wikis ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Now I understand what you mean by *"If I make funny phrase, it's because English is only my 3th language."* Is your list of question marks addressed to me (you don't know what I mean) or that you don't know what I should do to resolve this?

Comment: @Wikis - I think that was meant as a stream of profanities at the SE developers :)

Comment: @Wikis I posted it on meta : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118027/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-hypen-on-a-already-existing-tag-r2d2-r2-d2